# SendKeys.Send function not working

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I want to press Shift + Tab on some event , I am using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send` for that purpose but it is not working , I tried below ways to call the function.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                SendKeys.Send("{+(Tab)}");

 System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                SendKeys.Send("+{Tab}");

 System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                SendKeys.Send("{+}{Tab}");

 System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                SendKeys.Send("+{Tab 1}");
```

Can someone tell me what is the right way ?

Comment: Not working how? Not firing? How have you verified that they are not actually firing? "Not working" is the *worst* way you can describe an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by _it's not working_ how are you testing it?

Comment: +{TAB} is the correct syntax, and +{TAB 1} should also work.  The others will do something else.  (`+(Tab)` will send the shift, `T`, `A`, and `B` keys simultaneously; and `{+}{Tab}` will send the '+' key followed by `Tab`.  Is it correct to assume calling `.Focus()` on the element you want to set focus to is not an option?

Comment: The code gets called , I have ensure it but could not debug into Send function. It is not working because when I simply use Send("{Tab}"); it takes focus to next control in the FORM and want to take the focus backward i.e I want to mock the behaviour of original Shift + Tab key on some other event

Comment: @drf : I think it will be too hectic to find the control and call .Focus on it that is why I just want to call Shift + tab on the FORM , otherwise your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The proper syntax is:

```
SendKeys.Send("+{Tab}");
```

In light of your comment that you are trying to implement pressing `Shift+Tab` to cycle between control fields, note that this can be done more reliably without emulating keys.  This avoids issues where, for instance, another window has focus.

<strike>The following method will emulate the behavior of Shift_Tab, cycling through tab stops in reverse order:</strike>

```
void EmulateShiftTab()
{
    // get all form elements that can be focused
    var tabcontrols = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .Where(a => a.CanFocus)
            .OrderBy(a => a.TabIndex);

    // get the last control before the current focused element
    var lastcontrol =
            tabcontrols
            .TakeWhile(a => !a.Focused)
            .LastOrDefault(a => a.TabStop);

    // if no control or the first control on the page is focused,
    // select the last control on the page 
    if (lastcontrol == null)
           lastcontrol = tabcontrols.LastOrDefault();

    // change focus to the proper control
    if (lastcontrol != null)
           lastcontrol.Focus();
}
```

**Edit**

The deleted text will cycle through controls in reverse order (emulating shift+Tab), but this is more properly done with with the built-in `Form.SelectNextControl` method.  The following method will emulate the behavior of Shift_Tab, cycling through tab stops in reverse order.

```
void EmulateShiftTab()
{
    this.SelectNextControl(
        ActiveControl,
        forward: false,
        tabStopOnly:true, 
        nested: true, 
        wrap:true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it does nothing or sends input into control you don't want to be edited? Check if this code is called first, and dont't forget to focus on target control manually before SendKeys to make sure that it will receive your keys.